# JavaScript parses code before DOM

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom

I wanna ask that I am running a code which looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("named").onsubmit = () => {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        select_create();
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("channel_created").onsubmit = () => {
        success("Success!");
        return false;}});
```

*This code ensures that the code **should** run after the DOM is successfully being loaded.*
 However, the above block (document.getElementById("named")) works fine but when I open up console of browser, the console says:

> TypeError: document.getElementById("channel_created") is null

The HTML code has the form with id "channel_created". If I paste the same second block of code in console, it works. Am I missing some steps?

**Update:** I think I must show the HTML code, Here goes the relevant code:

```
        <div id="create">
        <form class="no-style" id="channel_created">
            <h1>Create a Channel to Talk (be specific)</h1>
            <div><input type="text" id="channel_name" name="channel_name" required placeholder="Please enter a channel name"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create a Channel Now!"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is `null`? Is there an error message? What exactly does the console say? Is the `channel_created` element dynamically created, e.g. by `select_create`? If so, then you need to bind the event _after_ `select_create();`.

Comment: Please see the Updated question, @Xufox .

Comment: @Ch.MuhammadSohaib but the code doesn't fail on `document.getElementById("named")`?

Comment: Exactly! @LuudJacobs, that's the confusing part.

Comment: Stop execution right before the call to `document.getElementById("channel_created")`. At that point in time, examine the DOM, and make sure the element is really there, with precisely the exactly matching name.

Comment: I tried, no id "channel_created".